# Partially de-normalization Vs de-normalization in Cassandra Data Modeling?

Tags: cassandra, duplicates, partial, denormalization, denormalized

I've read [this](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/) article about Cassandra Data modeling. But I didn't understand in which cases exactly **Partially de-normalization** is preferred? I've read some other articles which all of them use de-normalization (**not** partially).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Partial de-normalization** means that you **duplicate** only some columns of the target table.

**Full de-normalization** means you **duplicate all columns** of the target table

In practise, it is recommended to de-normalize, **IF POSSIBLE**, only **immutable** data so that you don't need to care about their update. In this case, duplicating only immutable data == partial de-normalization.